# ¿Cómo definir una única base de datos por defecto en Laravel cuando se tiene más de una conexión?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto que requiere conectarse a dos bases de datos, una local y otra externa (esta última es solo de lectura), aunque en el ejemplo manejo ambas en local, solo para pruebas.

Una tiene por nombre `mysql` la que trae por defecto el framework y a la otra le dí el nombre de `external`.

Así está configurado mi archivo `config/database.php`

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), // Está por defecto mysql

'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

    'external' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_EXTERNAL', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_EXTERNAL', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_EXTERNAL', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_EXTERNAL', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_EXTERNAL', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
],
```

Tengo ambas conexiones en el archivo `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=alerts
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=external
DB_HOST_EXTERNAL=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_EXTERNAL=3306
DB_DATABASE_EXTERNAL=properties
DB_USERNAME_EXTERNAL=root
DB_PASSWORD_EXTERNAL=
```

Al ejecutar `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` me ejecuta las migraciones en ambas tablas `properties` que corresponde a la conexión `external` y la tabla `alerts` que pertenece a la conexión local y está definida por defecto `mysql`, no debería ejecutar las migraciones en la tabla `alerts` solamente?

Eso lo solucioné creando las migraciones indicando la conexión de la siguiente manera `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --database=mysql` y en los modelos asigné la base de datos `protected $connection = 'mysql';`

El problema que se me presenta es el las notificaciones, al intentar cargar los datos en la tabla `jobs` me muetsra el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'properties.jobs' doesn't exist
```

Intenta guardarlas en la tabla `properties` y no en `alerts`.

Intenté agregar en el archivo de notificaciones  `protected $connection = 'mysql';` en `App\Notifications;` como lo hice en los Modelos y me muestra el siguiente error

```
App\Notifications\MessageSent and Illuminate\Bus\Queueable define the same property ($connection) in the composition of 
App\Notifications\MessageSent. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed
```

Notificaciones

```
public function handle()
{
    $properties = Property::orderBy('property_id', 'DESC')->whereDate('updated_date', '=', date('2022-06-07'))->get();

    foreach($properties as $key => $property) {
        
        $sent = Filter::where('district', $property->district)->where('subdistrict', $property->subdistrict)->first();

        $sent->user->notify(New MessageSent($property));
    }
}
```

Creo tener dos opciones, seleccionar por defecto la conexión `mysql` para todas las operaciones, ya que solo uso `properties` para lectura, o indicarle que la tabla `Jobs` no se encuentra en `properties` y en ambos casos no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Tenés el campo `DB_CONNECTION` repetido en tu `.env`. Deberías dejar solo tu DB por defecto y definir a mano desde el Modelo o donde tengas tu lógica cuando te querés conectar a otra DB.

Comment: Gracias, eso solucionó las migraciones, ahora con solo ejecutar `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` hace las migraciones en la tabla `alerts` solamente. Ahora no me lee el valor de `user` en el envío de la notificación `$sent->user->notify(New MessageSent($property));`, me muestra el siguiente error `Attempt to read property "user" on null`, pero al hacer un `dd($sent->user)` me muestra el registro del usuario.

Comment: No sé si está tratando de leer el `user` desde la base de datos `properties` pero en el modelo `User` la tengo definida en la conexión `mysql` que corresponde a la base de datos `Alerts`, de la siguiente manera `protected $connection = 'mysql';` `protected $table = 'users';`

Comment: Ese error lo que te está diciendo es que `$sent` es NULL, no "user". El `dd()` no debería funcionar. Lo más probable es que algunas de las veces `Filter` no devuelva nada. Antes del `$sent->user` poné un: `if ($sent == null) { dd($sent); }` a ver si encontrás el caso donde no te trae nada.

Comment: Disculpa salí muy temprano y regrese hace poco. Sí estuve verificando, como es un `foreach` hay registro que coinciden y otros no, agregué un condicional `if($sent != null)  { $sent->user->notify(New MessageSent($property)); }` y lo resuelve, ahora debo verificar porque no me hace el envío de las notificaciones. Gracias!